# Изменение содержимого объекта после клика (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, input, addeventlistener

Есть обьект содержащий набор email:password. Задача - при нажатии кнопки "Регистрация" взять полученные данные из инпутов и добавить их в этот самый обьект и потом уже использовать его для дальнейших операций.

Внутри функции (после клика) консоль отображает нужный мне результат, тоже самое необходимо при выводе во внешней консоли, чтобы можно было дальше манипулировать полученными данными из обновлённого объекта. Как это сделать, пока не могу разобрать, весь день вожусь..
Ниже код того что наваял. Первый раз пишу js, буду рад любой помощи в данном вопросе.

```
const dataBase = {
  'petrevanel@yahoo.com': '34gtLLsdf13#2445sdf$wfevreg__f431-_wf3',
  'yarikdsje@gmail.com': 'egt323Lf23$52%2;s',
  'sdfv2eb@protonmail.com': '23t5g34LLsdf5g322$@452',
}

Button.addEventListener('click', function () {

  const valueInputLow = valueInput.value.toLowerCase().split(' ').join('') //Значение email
  const passInputRes = passInput.value.split(' ').join('')//Значение password
 
  dataBase[valueInputLow] = passInputRes
  console.log(dataBase);
})

console.log(dataBase);
```

Comment: Так у вас второй консоль лог показывается только при первой загрузке страницы. Вы и так изменяете глобальный объект и он везде будет изменен.

Comment: Oliver Patterson, дело в том что дальше готовый обьект нужно преобразовать в массив и сверять новые данные из инпута с уже имеющимися в массиве. Так вот массив содержит только исходные 3 строки email:password, а новые (после изменения обьекта) не учитывает(

Comment: Не совсем понятно для чего есть объект и массив одновременно, хотя данные в них должны как-то совпадать... Зачем менять объект именно по нажатию на кнопку, если данные инпутов понадобятся потом и в массиве... Может когда они понадобятся - тогда читать инпуты и записывать в массив?

Comment: Хочу сделать регистрацию пользователя и сразу же проверять наличие/отсутствие пользователя через форму авторизации. Я не нашёл способа делать сверку пользователя через данные в обьекте, поэтому пришлось конвертировать обьект в массив)) Как в массиве сравнить новый login:password с уже имеющимся в базе, это я разобрался)) Так вот теперь нужно чтобы новые данные поступали в обьект, а после, этот обьект конвертировался в массив. Но получается что в массив они не поступают, в этом и беда. Понимаю, наверное каличная реализация. Но раз уж взялся, надо доделать, если это возможно вообще.

Comment: Делать нужно изначально правильно, в противном случае замучишь других и себя...